# Declaring `attr_reader` for all instance variables without listing them

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, you can create getter/setter methods by adding the following to the class definition.

```
attr_reader :key1, :key2, :key4
attr_writer :key1, :key2, :key3
```

or equivalently

```
attr_accessor :key1, :key2, :key3
```

For example

```
class Foo
    attr_reader :blah, :bar, :foo, :rah, :jar

    def initialize a, b, c
        @blah = calculate_blah(a,b)
        @bar  = calculate_bar(a)
        @foo  = calculate_foo(b,c)
        @rah  = calculate_rah(a,b,c)
        @jar  = calculate_jar(a,c)
    end
    # etc etc
end
```

Let's say there are many instance variables, and I want getter methods
on all of them.

Is it possible to declare `attr_reader` on all the instance variables without listing them all out?

The benefit is so that you don't have to maintain two lists of variables (which are identical) one in the `initialize` method, another with `attr_reader`.  So later if you want to add another instance variable, you only have to set it up in the `initialize` method, without needing to add it to the `attr_reader` list too.

If this isn't readily available with `attr_reader`, perhaps some metaprogramming could be summoned to help?

The main objective here is to understand if this is possible in Ruby.
Using metaprogramming often incurs cost of performance and obscurity.  But that's beyond the scope of this question.

I'm more interested in knowing if it's possible to do something, not whether that's the right thing to do.

Comment: you got a array of these instance variables's names?

Comment: Instance variables do not exist before runtime. They spring to life when they are assigned a value. This means that different instances of the same class can have different sets of instance variables, depending on the logic executed in them. Now that you know this, at which point in object's lifecycle do you want to create the methods?

Comment: "perhaps some metaprogramming magic could help" - your exact use case is very unclear, but if it's out of pure laziness, then you shouldn't involve metaprogramming. A class with 100 ivars is bad enough :)

Comment: How would you plan to enumerate the names all of your instance variables? If you can enumerate the names of the variables, then it's simply: `(my variable name enumerator).each { |var| attr_reader var }`.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by with/without listing them.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You have made a very good point.  I think you're implying adding some metaprogramming at the end of the `initialize` method, to create setters or getters that way.  Thank you.

Comment: @ZackXu: yeah, you could do that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev All programmers are lazy by nature.  If not, they would be entering numbers in massive spreadsheets.  So in this sense, laziness is a virtue, and mother of all programming inventions.  The identical twin of laziness is automation.

Comment: @ZackXu: if you are looking to reduce duplication in your code (as in the DRY principle), then you should also know that not all duplication is to be removed. There is also _incidental_ duplication, when some parts are similar, but for different reasons. In this case, the body of `initialize` is setting the __state__ of the object, and attr_accessor call is defining __public API__ of the class. Quite different things, in my opinion.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I agree with you.  In practice, not all instance variables of an object should be exposed to the external world.  This is the principle of encapsulation and information hiding.  But in my example, all the instance variables are to be exposed, because this is a simple object.  This is a theoretical question about HOW to do something.

Comment: @ZackXu: `define_method` is what you need.

Comment: @ZackXu: "because this is a simple object" - if it really was a simple object, it'd be an OpenStruct or Struct. In reality, it appears to have loads of logic (all those `calculate_XXX` methods)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose

```
class A
  def initialize
    @b=0
    @c=1
  end
end
```

Then

```
a = A.new

a.instance_variables.each { |iv| self.class.send(:attr_reader, iv.to_s[1..-1].to_sym) }

a.b #=> 0
a.c #=> 1
```

If all the instance variables are defined in `initialize` you could write

```
class A
  def initialize
    @b=0
    @c=1
    instance_variables.each do |iv|
      self.class.send(:attr_reader, iv.to_s[1..-1].to_sym)
    end
  end
end

a = A.new
a.b #=> 0
a.c #=> 1
```

Comment: @Marcos, thank you for the edit. I made a lot of mistakes back then, when I was just a kid.

Comment: ...@Marcos's proposed edit? A quick perusal of your profile provides no evidence that you are familiar with Ruby, a prerequisite, I would think, for passing judgement on the proposed edit.

Comment: Awesome, this just saved me a whole bunch of typing!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using singleton method.  Note `create_getters` is a private method, so the outside world is not aware of the use of metaprogramming (implementation detail).

```
class Foo
  def initialize a, b
    @foo = a + b
    @bar = a - b
    @jar = a + b + 1000

    create_getters
  end

  private

  def create_getters
    instance_variables.each do |v|
      define_singleton_method(v.to_s.tr('@','')) do
        instance_variable_get(v)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

running this in irb:

```
2.2.1 :082 > x=Foo.new 100, 99
 => #<Foo:0x007fb4f3c31ce8 @foo=199, @bar=1, @jar=1199>
2.2.1 :083 > x.foo
 => 199
2.2.1 :084 > x.bar
 => 1
2.2.1 :085 > x.jar
 => 1199
```

Be warned: by doing it this way, object instantiation and getter method invocation are both SLOWER.

Answer (score 1):

Even though, as other have said, it is not a good idea to actually use similar code, it's possible to write the meta-function you are asking for.
This is one of many possible different solution. The idea is that you augment every object you are using once in their life cycle, when the instance variable are already defined on the object. This could happen during, or after, the initialization.

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @a = @b = @c = 33
    # you could call define_attr_readers here
  end

  def define_attr_readers
    # get the eigenclass of the current object
    klass = class << self; self; end

    symbols = instance_variables.map { |s|
      # remove the @ at the start of the symbol
      s.to_s[1..-1].to_sym
    }

    # augment the eigenclass
    klass.class_eval do
      symbols.each do |s|
        attr_reader s
      end
    end
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.define_attr_readers
p f.a, f.b, f.c
```

Comment: The official term for the "eigenclass" is "singleton class" now. There's even a getter for it, `singleton_class`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  We see the power of Ruby's metaprogramming.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the class once to evaluate the instance variables and re-define the class

```
class Hey 
  def initialize
    @foo, @bar, @shabaz = [1,2,3]
  end 
end

Hey.new.instance_variables.tap do |inst_vars|
  Hey.class_eval do
    attr_reader *inst_vars.map { |var| var.to_s.sub(/^@/, '').to_sym }
  end 
end

p Hey.new.foo
p Hey.new.bar
p Hey.new.shabaz
```